# jQuery context is null + IE bug not showing contact/bio boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found an open-source code that was perfect for my husbands website. I changed it to our liking, but it keeps giving an annoying error in the console:

Unable to get property "ownerDocument" of undefined of null reference.

In Firefox it says simply: TypeError: context is null

the error is supposedly here: jquery-1.10.2.js, line 1822 character 2

```
Sizzle.contains = function( context, elem ) {
   // Set document vars if needed
   if ( ( context.ownerDocument || context ) !== document ) {
        setDocument( context );
   }
   return contains( context, elem );
};
```

I think I am doing something wrong in my code, but I can't seem to say where.

Also there is a weird IE error: The contact and bio page dissappear, when I open the menu, it is there, but it only comes foreward when I select that part of the page, and then it dissappears. I don't know if it is anything to do with the above error.

It works fine on Safari, Firefox, Chrome, but most of the visitors use IE.

HTML CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"    
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>Franklin Cando - Photographe</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Franklin Cando - Photographe" />
    <meta name="keywords" content=""/>
<!--I added this as a test, since I saw somewhere that this could help-->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=6" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/icons/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/Quicksand_Book_400.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Cufon.replace('span,p,h1',{
    textShadow: '0px 0px 1px #ffffff'
     });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m) 
       {
          i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},
               i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
       m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)0];
               a.async=1;
               a.src=g;
               m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-
                 analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
      ga('create', 'UA-44223947-1', 'franklincando.com');
      ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
   </head>
<body>
  <div id="st_main" class="st_main">
<img src="images/album/AK9A4519.jpg" alt="" class="st_preview" id="bigImage"  
     style="display:none;"/>
<div class="st_overlay"></div>
<h1>
       <a class="titelLink" href="http://www.franklincando.com/">Franklin Cando</a>
    </h1>
<div id="st_loading" class="st_loading"><span>Loading...</span></div>
<ul id="st_nav" class="st_navigation">
   <li>
      <span class="st_link">Biographie<span class="st_arrow_down"></span></span>
      <div class="st_about st_thumbs_wrapper">
        <div class="st_subcontent">
     <table>
      <!--CONTENT-->
     </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
       <span class="st_link">Contact<span class="st_arrow_down"></span></span>
       <div class="st_about st_thumbs_wrapper" id="form_div_parent">
       <div class="st_subcontent" id="form_div_child">
        <div class="contactinfo" id="contactinfo_div">
      <h3>Contact</h3><br/>
       <!--CONTENT-->
      <form id="contactForm" method="post" action="php/send_form.php" >
        <!--CONTENT-->
        <input class="button" type="button" onclick="validateForm()" 
                     value="Envoyer"/>
        <input class="button" type="reset" onclick="resetForm()" 
                     value="Effacer"/>
      </form>
        </div>
      </div>
        </li>
    <li class="album">
    <span class="st_link">Photos<span class="st_arrow_down"></span></span>
    <div class="st_wrapper st_thumbs_wrapper" id="wrapper">
      <div class="st_thumbs" id="thumbs">
        <!--IMAGES-->
      </div>
    </div>
    </li>
</ul>
  </div> 
 </body>
</html>
```

JQUERY-JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function() {

   //the loading image
   var $loader = $('#st_loading');

   //the ul element 
   var $list = $('#st_nav');

   //the current image being shown
   var $currImage = $('#st_main').children('img:first');

   //the facebook button - iris
   var $fb = $('#fb');
   $fb.hide();

   //let's load the current image and just then display the navigation menu
   $('<img>').load(function(){
      $loader.hide();

  if ($currImage.width() > $currImage.height()){
     $currImage.css({"width":"100%"});
  }

  $currImage.fadeIn(3000);
  //slide out the menu
  setTimeout(function(){
    $list.animate({'left':'0px'},500);
    $fb.show();
  },1000);

}).attr('src',$currImage.attr('src'));

//calculates the width of the div element where the thumbs are going to be 
    displayed

buildThumbs();

function buildThumbs(){
    $list.children('li.album').each(function(){
    var $elem = $(this);
    var $thumbs_wrapper = $elem.find('.st_thumbs_wrapper');
    var $thumbs = $thumbs_wrapper.children(':first');

             //each thumb has 180px and we add 3 of margin
    var finalW = $thumbs.find('img').length * 183;
    $thumbs.css('width',finalW + 'px');

    //make this element scrollable
    makeScrollable($thumbs_wrapper,$thumbs);
      });
}

//clicking on the menu items (up and down arrow)
//makes the thumbs div appear, and hides the current opened menu (if any)

    $(document).on('click','.st_arrow_down',function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    hideThumbs();
        $this.addClass('st_arrow_up').removeClass('st_arrow_down');
    var $elem = $this.closest('li');
            $elem.addClass('current').animate({'height':'170px'},200);
    var $thumbs_wrapper = $this.parent().next();
    $thumbs_wrapper.show();
});

$(document).on('click','.st_arrow_up',function(){
    var $this = $(this);
        $this.addClass('st_arrow_down').removeClass('st_arrow_up');
    hideThumbs();
});

//clicking on a thumb, replaces the large image
$(document).on('click','.st_thumbs img',function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $loader.show();
    $('<img class="st_preview"/>').load(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var $currImage = $('#st_main').children('img:first');
        $this.insertBefore($currImage);
        if ($this.width() > $this.height()){    
                        $this.css({"width":"100%"});
                    }
        $loader.hide();
        $currImage.fadeOut(2000,function(){
             $(this).remove();
            });
           }).attr('src',$this.attr('alt'));
}).bind('mouseenter',function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({'opacity':'1'});
}).bind('mouseleave',function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({'opacity':'0.7'});
});


//hide image menu upon mouse out - iris
$list.find('.st_thumbs').bind('mouseleave',function(){
    hideThumbs();
});

//function to hide the current opened menu  //.css({"display":"none"}) // to hide 
     the bigger text boxes - iris
function hideThumbs(){
    $list.find('li.current').animate({'height':'50px'},400,
                                     function(){
                        $(this).removeClass('current');
                     })
                     .find('.st_thumbs_wrapper')
                     .hide()
                     .andSelf()
                     .find('.st_link span')
                     .addClass('st_arrow_down')
                     .removeClass('st_arrow_up');
}

//makes the thumbs div scrollable on mouse move the div scrolls automatically

    function makeScrollable($outer, $inner){
    var extra = 800;
    //Get menu width
    var divWidth = $outer.width();
    //Remove scrollbars
    $outer.css({overflow:'hidden'});
    //Find last image in container
    var lastElem = $inner.find('img:last');
    $outer.scrollLeft(0);
    //When user move mouse over menu
    $outer.unbind('mousemove').bind('mousemove',function(e){
                    var containerWidth = lastElem[0].offsetLeft 
                                               + lastElem.outerWidth() + 2*extra;
                    var left = (e.pageX - $outer.offset().left) 
                                               * (containerWidth-divWidth) / divWidth - 
                                            extra;
                    $outer.scrollLeft(left);
                });
            }
        });

   </script>
```

The website: [www.franklincando.com](http://www.franklincando.com/)

PS: really sorry about indentation. I spent a lot of time making it right in this post, and upon posting it still doesn't look like it is supposed to. I hope it is still clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rebuilding the project. The base code I was using was for an older version of jQuery and I added the newest libraries. I think the code clashed on that. Working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is here:

```
$(document)
/* ... */
.bind('mouseenter',function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({'opacity':'1'});
}).bind('mouseleave',function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({'opacity':'0.7'});
});
```

In this case, `this` is the `document`.  You can't animate the opacity of the document.  Change it to `body` instead and it should be fine.

```
$("body").bind('mouseenter',function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({'opacity':'1'});
}).bind('mouseleave',function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({'opacity':'0.7'});
});
```

Comment: Oh, ok thanks :) that solves the console error! But i'm still left with the weird bug in IE :/ I thought they might be related, but no... The contact/bio boxes still don't show on opening the menu items, but they are there alright... no idea what that could be?